# Gas limit per block

Tags: gas, gas-limit

Gas limit per block is a dynamic value. This value is increasing every year. Is it theoretically possible that such a value can somehow decrease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block limit can increase or decrease, depending on what the miners choose.

The miners have a limited ability to adjust this value in order to help (or hurt) the network.

This value has been changed at times of high network stress, such as [when there were too many transactions](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6ehp60/recommendations_to_miners_to_change_gas_limit_and/#ampf=undefined) to process and also when there was an ongoing DDOS attack.